# Tkinter one button multiple commands

Tags: python, tkinter

This is not the full code, only snippets of which I'm trying to get to work.

I should warn, I'm still in the learning phases of Python, so if you see anything funky, that's why.

I'm using Tkinter to design a GUI and I want to have a single button press start a handful of commands all at once.

To elaborate on what this program does, it starts an iperf client and then captures telnet readings at the same time. I had a great proof of concept in bash working, but with tkinter I can only seem to get one to start right after the first one has already finished. Using the lambda method below the compiler still complains:

TypeError: () takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

```
    self.iperfr = Button(frame, text="---Run---",command = lambda x:self.get_info() & self.telnetcap()) 
    self.iperfr.pack(side=BOTTOM)


    def get_info():

    iperf= self.iperfc.get()
    time = self.timeiperf.get()
    iperfcommand= 'iperf -c 127.0.0.1 -y c -i 1  {}'.format(iperf)+ ' -t {}'.format(time)
    print iperfcommand      
    os.system(iperfcommand)

    def telnetcap():

    n=0 


    time = self.timeiperf.get()

    child=pexpect.spawn('telnet 192.168.2.1');
    child.logfile = open("/home/alex/Desktop/Test", "w")
    child.expect('Login:');
    child.sendline('telnet');

    child.expect('Password:');
    child.sendline('password');

    while (n<time):
        child.expect('>');
        child.sendline('sh');

        child.expect('#') ;
        child.sendline ('sysinfo');

        child.expect ('#');
        child.sendline ('iostat');
        child.expect ('#');
        child.sendline ('exit');

        n=n+1
        print n
```

At this point I feel like it might be easier to actually just call my original bash script from within this Python GUI. It seems so trivial, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get it to work. The simple "&" in bash did exactly what I wanted it to do. Is there a Python version of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're not using the argument anyway, try changing the `command` keyword argument to `command=lambda:self.get_info() & self.telnetcap()`.

Comment: That did get it to compile, however now they're still running one after the other. So much for lambda.

Comment: The `command` argument of a button can be the name of a function containing multiple statements, each of which will generally be executed in succession. If you want them to run in parallel, use something like the `subprocess` module in the function.

Comment: The succession is the problem, they need to run simultaneously.

Comment: The `subprocess` module has functions to start independent processes without necessarily waiting for each one to finish before starting the next.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken subprocess is better suited for calling external processes, which was something I was trying to avoid by keeping all my code confined to one file. I've skimmed through the documentation but nothing has jumped out at me that would allow me to call internal functions as a sub process.

Comment: You might be able to use the [`threading` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) to effectively run them concurrently. That can be tricky when using `tkinter`, but if these other threads don't affect the GUI then it would be viable.

Comment: I think you're right in saying threading is the way to go. It's really kind of annoying that for bash to do this a simple "&" works great. I've dug and dug and still can't find any sort of equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Martineau for pointing me in the right direction. Threading was definitely the way to go. By assigning my "run_all" button to a function designated to start individual threads it works great.

```
def run_all(self):
    thread.start_new_thread(self.telnetcap, ())
    thread.start_new_thread(self.get_info, ())
```